# Can a website be considered as a "place"?

Tags: word-usage, phrases

I'm working on a text for a website and don't know, if it would be a mistake to use this phrase:

> Website.com is the **place** where the World Meets!

I googled it to see if anyone used similar phrases but couldn't find any. Is "place" possible or should I go for something else like "spot" / "hot spot" etc.?

Comment: I think the way you have it is fine, but it sounds better to me if you leave that part out altogether and write: “Website.com is where the world meets!” (I wouldn't capitalize “world” or “meets” unless that’s the name of the site.) _As a side note, we prefer to avoid code formatting here. Please use blockquotes (>) to call out a sentence or more, and either quotation marks (“”) or italics to indicate the mention of single words._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It's an analogy, of course. A website is not really a physical location. But people routinely refer to websites as "places". The very word, "website", includes the word "site", which refers to a place.

Lots of abstract groupings like this are discussed as places. People will say, "Foobar Labs is a place where the future is being built today", or "The Democratic Party is a place where people work together to ..." whatever it is they think they're doing.

Comment: And ELL is a "place" to ask questions like this one!

Comment: I still think “...is where...” is a more natural construction. It doesn’t add anything to include “a/the place”, because that idea of _location_ is already conveyed with “where” and having both feels... inefficient.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung That's an important point, but that's a different question than whether you **can** refer to it as a place.  (To which the answer is: yes, you can!)

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung It would certainly be redundant sometimes. But consider a sentence like, "McDonalds is a place where you can get hamburgers." If I tried to drop the "place", I'd end up with, "McDonalds is where you can get hamburgers", which sounds like I'm saying it's the ONLY such place. Of course one could recast the sentence, like, "You can get hamburgers at McDonalds." But that shifts the emphasis from "McDonalds" to "hamburgers". I'm sure there are other possible wordings, but sometimes words that seem redundant at first glance cannot just be dropped.

Comment: @snailboat The question is phrased around use of the indefinite article, but the example itself uses the definite article. I agree that both are possible, but I believe that the redundancy should be mentioned so the OP knows why that phrasing sounds a little awkward.

Comment: @Jay The key difference is the article. Your example uses the indefinite article, which is what makes the meaning different without "place". "McDonald's is the place where you can get hamburgers" and "McDonald's is where you can get hamburgers" have the same (false) implication that McDonald's is the only place one can get hamburgers. Since OP's example uses the definite article with "(the) place", which is redundant with "where", I think it should be mentioned.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung Oh, yes, true, going back to the original example, "Website.com is the place where the world meets" and "Website.com is where the world meets" mean pretty much the same thing. In that case "the place" doesn't add any information. Perhaps it makes it more emphatic.